# Calculating residual sum of squares and standard error from linearFit model

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used the linearFit() reducer to get trend analysis for NDVI (dependent variable), and time (t) is my one independent value.

What code can I use to calculate the residual sum of squares and standard error from this linearFit model in google earth engine?

Comment: in theory this should be possible with `ee.Reducer.linearRegression` but for me this solution always times out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Use `ee.Reducer.linearRegression()` instead of `ee.linearFit()`. Then you can take R2 from the band called `'residuals'`.
2. You go from the definition of [image: r2] and code it yourself.

For my dataset, option 1 resulted in a timeout but you might get different mileage. Hence, I'll describe how to code [image: r2] from it's definition. For instance over at Wikipedia the definition is given by:

[image: formula]

For an explanation of the symbols, check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). In addition I used [image: formula] for the variance and [image: n] for the count of datapoints. I turned this formula into the following code and got decent performance.

```
var varcount_reducer = ee.Reducer.variance().combine(ee.Reducer.count(), '', true);
image_collection = image_collection.map(function (img) {
  return img.addBands(img.metadata('system:time_start'));
});
var trend_img = image_collection
  .select(['system:time_start', 'sigma0'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

// calculate R_squared, the coefficient of determination
// R_squared = 1 - SS_res / SS_tot
var offset = trend_img.select('offset');
var scale = trend_img.select('scale');
var SS_res = image_collection.map( function (img) {
  var fit = offset.add(img.select('system:time_start').multiply(scale)); // y_bar
  var error = img.select('sigma0').subtract(fit); // y_i - y_bar
  return error.multiply(error); // squared
}).sum();
var SS_tot = change_coll.reduce(varcount_reducer).expression(
"b('sigma0_variance')*b('sigma0_count')");
var r2 = SS_res.divide(SS_tot).multiply(-1).add(1.0).rename('r2');
trend_img.addBands(r2);
```